# Kitchen faucet leak worsened after O-Ring replacement

Tags: plumbing, leak, faucet

My kitchen sink has a Moen model 1225 faucet, like the one pictured: [image: Moen 1225].

I replaced the O-rings because of a leak around the handle (not the nozzle).

I'm wondering if I installed the O-rings incorrectly or if my faucet (~16 years old) needs to be replaced? My region has very hard water. When installing the rings, I did try applying the silicone grease to them.

The leak has gotten worse after the replacing the rings. Many times a steady stream of water will run out of the handle, although sometime rotating the handle reduces this to a trickle.

Before originally installing the rings, I soaked the faucet parts in a diluted vinegar solution until most of the mineral build up flaked off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try calling Moen about it since their faucets carry a lifetime warranty. They would send you out a new o-ring at no charge.

The O-ring you got as a replacement may not be the correct size unless it came from Moen. If it is the correct size and the faucet leaks, then the faucet parts themselves may have worn out to the point that a new o-ring won't be able to fix the leak.

Answer (score 1):

I find that replacing the whole cartridge rather than the o-rings usually works well, specifically for leaks out the opening of the tap. For leaks around the base, the o-rings need to be replaced.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.